# In Fedora, list all the commands associated with a Package

Tags: linux, fedora

Why are the names of the packages and their corresponding commands' name are different in GNU/Linux? For example, a package named "ripgrep" has associated command by the name "rg". How do I list all the command names associated with a package in fedora?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Ravphys. Your question isn't so much a programming question as it is a Linux question. I suggest you move it to https://unix.stackexchange.com/ I think it is likelier to be answered there.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I flagged it for migration. If I'm correct, a moderator would be assisting you shortly.

Comment: `rpm -ql package_name` will list the files in an installed RPM package. Look for paths in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: That solves the problem! Thanks!

Comment: If you want to see the files that would be installed before installing them, in this case, `dnf repoquery ripgrep --list` will do that.  `dnf repoquery` is very much like a remote `rpm -q`.